# schema.describefieldresult how to cover when i pass field name and objecet name occur Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Contact

Tags: unit-test, schema

class part

```
public static Schema.DescribeFieldResult gettingDataType(String fieldName,ObjectType oType){
         Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(toString(oType)).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
         //String type = objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
         return objectFields.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
    }
```

Test class part

```
ConflictManager.gettingDataType('FirstName',contact);
```

Comment: I have a doubt `ObjectType` compiled successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to presume you meant `SObjectType`, not `ObjectType`, in which case, you need to use the `SObjectType` property of a Schema object. Here's how you'd fix this line:

```
ConflictManager.gettingDataType('FirstName',Contact.SObjectType);
```

However, if you were going to go this route, you could skip the global describe:

```
public static Schema.DescribeFieldResult gettingDataType(String fieldName,SObjectType oType){
    return oType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldName).getDescribe();
}
```

Of course, when possible, you should use direct field references, which avoids any extra describes at all:

```
DescribeFieldResult fieldDetails = Contact.FirstName.getDescribe();
```

The only time you'd go through all the hassle of a global describe is because you really can't think of any better way to get to your data type.